# Splitting a cell in RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I need to split a cell into 4 cells in one row and the subsequent rows will have normal cells. How can we do that using a matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a row with 4 cell, then doing merge for another row..